# Decrementing model value at midnight in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I want to decrement the value days_till_study with 1 everyday at midnight.

My current approach is not very elegant. Is there a better way to do this?

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
    
class Card(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    answer = models.TextField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    decks = models.ManyToManyField(Deck)
    days_till_study = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

    def decrement_days_till_study(self):
        if days_till_study < 1:
            x = str(datetime.datetime.now())
            if x[x[11:26]] == '00:00:00.000000':
                days_till_study += 1
```

Thanks for reading this.

Comment: What is the purpose of days_till_study? Could this not be derived from another piece of data in the model? Is it suppose to mirror days left until the date set on the card?

Comment: So days_till_study is incremented through a button another place on the webapp. I also use days_till_study as a filter to show certain cards. I'm building a spaced_repition app. 
"Is it suppose to mirror days left until the date set on the card?" - In this context, I suppose so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Calculating the result on the fly

If you have control over what to store in the database, it's better to store both days in the database and calculate the difference based on it:

```py
class Card(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    study_at = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def days_till_study(self):
        return (self.study_at - self.created_at).days
```

### Scheduling via Celery

If you still need to do something by a schedule (like updating `days_till_study` at midnight) you can try [django-cron](https://pypi.org/project/django-cron/) library or another Celery-based solution.

### Scheduling via cron

Also, you can create a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/) and run it by a schedule via the system [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron).

Comment: Went with cron. Works perfectly. Thanks