# Is there a way that I can make a python command get sent at exactly midnight?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a booking script that will book an event at exactly midnight. I have writen all the code and it all works I just need to activate the book command at exactly midnight. Many Thanks if you can help me out

Comment: If you are using a linux machine, you can create a cron-job.

Comment: You need to know where you want it to be executed. For linux the crontab is the place, but the machine will need to be up then.

Comment: The second and third options (using celery and cron) from this answer should work for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63448762/8704691

Comment: Just for completness: Linux machines with systemd (i.e. almost all recent ones) can have timer units which periodically call corresponding serice units. Setting up a cron job is much easier; OTOH systemd has many additional features.

Answer (score 7):

You can either:

#### Use the schedule module

Start with installing it from pip with: `pip install schedule`
And then you can use that module like that:

```
import schedule

def foo():
    print("Fooing around")

schedule.every().day.at("00:00").do(foo)
```

#### Use cron job (On Linux and macOS)

Use the command: `crontab -e` to edit the cron jobs.
Add the following line to execute your script every midnight:

```
00 00 * * * python /path/to/script.py
```

Comment: Instead of calling a function, can you set it up to run a .py file?

Comment: @vestland For running a `.py` file you should probably go with the second option of using a cron job. If you don't want to (or can't) do that, and want to stick to the first solution you can: 1.point it to a function that calls `subprocess.call` 2.import your target file in that script and give it's main function to the `schedule`

Comment: I'm on a windows system so I guess it's `Task Scheduler` for me then